# Trying to execute a if/else statement in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to execute a simple `JQuery` code a.k.a an `if/else` statement. Here's my code:

```
$('#butt_click, #pary').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id').val() == "butt_click") {
    alert("You clicked button");
    } else {
    alert("You clicked pary");
    }
});
```

The code above doesn't work AT ALL. Can't seem to find the problem... Help would be appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: I'm sorry.. I'm new to javascript and i have no idea what that means

Comment: @ADeveloper A 'fiddle' is a code example created in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn’t look right:

```
$(this).attr('id').val()
```

Try using `$(this).attr('id')` or simply `this.id` instead (if you are trying to access the `id` property from the clicked element).

Answer (score 2):

You have wrong code.

code must be as below.

```
if ($(this).val() == "butt_click")
```

**OR**

```
if ($(this).attr('id') == "butt_click")
```

**not**

```
if ($(this).attr('id').val() == "butt_click")
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `val()`.   `$(this).attr('id')`  already returns `value`

```
 if ($(this).attr('id') == "butt_click") {
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove **.val()** from if statement

Change your if statement to

```
if ($(this).attr('id') == "butt_click") {
    alert("You clicked button");
} else {
    alert("You clicked pary");
}
```